# Pass an array or record to a function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, functions, array, composite-types, postgresql-9.0

I have a task to pass arrays, records, and in some cases array of records as a parameter to functions in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Postgres has very flexible handling of [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) and [composite types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html). This may be the sort of thing you are trying to do:

> ```
> create type my_type as (val1 integer, val2 integer);
> ```

> ```
> create function my_function(arr my_type[]) returns text language plpgsql as $$
> begin
>   return arr::text;
> end;$$;
> ```

> ```
> select my_function(array[row(1,2),row(3,4)]::my_type[]);
> ```
>
> ```
> | my_function       |
> | :---------------- |
> | {"(1,2)","(3,4)"} |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=207971f904ff986920e88a9cd76bcab6)*