# Passing array with varying dimensions to postgres function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to process a group of transactions as one transaction with Postgres.

I receive a group of transactions to process which I want to pass to Postgres to process all together or not at all.

There are a few different types of transactions that each have their own stored procedure to handle.  Ideally I am looking to pass a Javascript array of dictionaries for the Postgres function to iterate through and then check a field for the type of job to call the correct procedure. Sort of like this pseduo code

```
create or replace procedure processblock(  array )
begin
   for item in array
       if item.jobtype = 'buyitem'
            call buyitem(item.name, item.quantity)
       if item.jobtype = 'sellitem'
            call sellitem(item.name, item.quantity)
       if item.jobtype = 'postad'
            call postad(item.adname, item.adtext, item.adurl)
       if item.jobtype = 'updatestate'
            call updatestate(item.laststate)
```

So I want to be able pass a group of jobs that get handled by a function by calling the appropriate stored procedure with have varying arguments (array of dictionaries or json) meaning I need to pass items of various sizes.

I am using Postgres 13.  I have seen [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/pass-an-array-or-record-to-a-function-in-postgresql) question, and the answer, but it doesn't seem to cover an array of variadic arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do it. The important part is to keep it as the `json` type until you get to the dispatching part; at that point, just extract the relevant args for that sub-type using regular json operators (see dispatching_function in the example).

```sql
-- in dispatching_func.psql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_the_first(thing_name text, quantity integer, out bar text)
as $$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'first_kind, thing %, quantity %', thing_name, quantity;
return;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_the_second(adname text, adtext text, adurl text, out foo text)
as $$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'second_kind, adname %, adtext %, adurl %', adname, adtext, adurl;
return;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dispatching_function(input_data json, out foo text)
AS $$
BEGIN
IF ((input_data->>'kind') = 'first_kind') THEN
  perform function_the_first(input_data->>'name', (input_data->>'quantity')::integer);
ELSIF ((input_data->>'kind') = 'second_kind') THEN
  perform function_the_second(input_data->>'adname', input_data->>'adtext', input_data->>'adurl');
END IF;
return;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dispatching_function_per_element(input_data json, out foo text)
AS $$
DECLARE elm json;
BEGIN
FOR elm in SELECT elem from json_array_elements(input_data) as elem
LOOP
PERFORM dispatching_function(elm::json);
END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

----

testdb=# \i dispatching_func.psql 
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
testdb=# select dispatching_function_per_element(
$$
[{"kind": "first_kind", "name": "asdf", "quantity": 2},
 {"kind": "second_kind", "adname": "my ad", "adtext": "buy stuff", "adurl": "example.com"}]
 $$::json);
NOTICE:  first_kind, thing asdf, quantity 2
NOTICE:  second_kind, adname my ad, adtext buy stuff, adurl example.com
 dispatching_function_per_element 
----------------------------------
 
(1 row)
```